# Unable to extract text using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the text after "Pros" on this website https://www.getapp.ca/reviews/2035391/voip-ms
but its proving to be difficult due to my rudimentary understanding of web scraping.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
voip_p = open("voip.ms_pros.txt")
page = 1 
with open('voip.ms_pros.txt', 'a') as voip_p:
  while page != 15:
    url = f"https://www.getapp.ca/reviews/2035391/voip-ms/page={page}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    for t in soup.select('p:-soup-contains("Pros")'):
      print(t.get_text(strip=True), file=voip_p)
      print('-' * 80, file=voip_p)
    page = page + 1
```

This is my code so far that isn't working. How do I go about fixing this so I'm able to retrieve the text after Pros? Any resources to learn how to do this kind of stuff would also help because I was never formally taught and I'm just going by what I'm seeing online.

Thanks!

Comment: _This is my code so far that isn't working_ Saying that your code "isn't working" does not actually tell us anything about the problem.  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected results?  Or empty results?  You have to **tell us what the code actually does**, and then **explain how that is different from what you wanted**.

Comment: However, since I see that you're using `requests` to fetch the page content, I'll make a guess that the problem is javascript.  Many websites use javascript to create the page content, but `requests` cannot process javascript.  If this is the problem, you'll have to use some other way to fetch the page content that is javascript-aware.

Comment: oh I mean that nothing comes up, it runs but nothing gets retrieved from the page its just blank. So I'm assuming my code isn't right

Answer (score 0):

You have your CSS selector wrong. The "Pros" text is inside `<h4>` element on this page, not `<p>`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.getapp.ca/reviews/2035391/voip-ms'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for t in soup.select('h4:-soup-contains("Pros") + div'):
    print(t.get_text(strip=True))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reliable VOIP provider, with features beyond just a simple VOIP line, they offer features like IVR, Voicemail, SMS, Call recording, In some cases we use VOIP.MS in lieu of a PBX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
So flexible with so many features, it allows us to customize our front end almost perfectly. Now, with added number availability, I've been able to bring all of our numbers in-house.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Very easy to set up and manage with good controls on use, coupled with great pricing and a very responsive support staff. What else can you want - oh yes - great quality on calls - which VoIP.ms delivers on as well!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```